How to keeping data field/attribute/column names consistent throughout a project?
In any Python project or in other language we need to use same fields name at various places throughout the project processing pipeline. Such requirement is omnipresence and often leads to errors, debugging time and code breaking at runtime. So, how we can keep the fields/attributes/column names consistent throughout the project. (to avoid typos, mismatch names etc)
Let understand the problem with an example:
Suppose, my project involves using data scraping for data collection and then store and serve it through back-end infrastructure (web application or API).

Now, if, i use Scrapy for data scraping then i have to create Item() with required data fields (suppose: book_title, author, pages and price), later same fields name should be used in spiders for data scraping which may get saved as JSON .

The json file may be dump to a database directly (to populate data for an application) then the table/s needs to be created in database , possibly with same names to avoid errors.

Similarly, if Django is used as backend, then the model and serializer will also have these fields name, so again we need to repeat same fields names.

if we want to do some data operation, suppose with pandas then either we can import JSON or may create dataframe manually (repeating the fields name).


We can see that in one project, we need to repeat the fields name multiple time. Variations in name may or maynot lead to errors or issues. However, being consistent with name is good and safe with big projects.
So, what is the best possible ways to achieve it? When, i started working on this many python modules pops up, but most of them are heavy and offers many features that is either supported in individual packages/framework and integrating those with external packages create conflicts and unnecessary loads on the project.
I want some thing very simple, like just text file etc .
Note: I am not asking for any type hint or data validations etc. just want to have consistent field name. for example, student_name, name, stu_name, should be just anyone throughout the project.
I tried many package offering class based features for creating datamodels. Like, Pydantic, Itemloader, marshmallow, attrib , etc.
For example, following code gives use fields name that can be used in other part of the project but this seems like overdoing by using Pydantic just to get fields name:
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List, Optional

class NoteSchema(BaseModel):
    title: str
    content: str
    tags: List[str]
    user_id: int
    created_at: Optional[str] = None

# Get the list of field names from the Pydantic model
field_names = list(NoteSchema.model_fields.keys())


print(field_names)


you are probably after some sort of data dictionary, check out https://www.splunk.com/en_us/blog/learn/data-dictionary.html gives a basic outline . this should be(come) a single immutable source for all fields ... obviously you can add/modify the layout of that to suit your project  team specifics, access control should be managed - don't let just anyone modify it - make sure its under version control - git ... etc

IMO unless you build something custom for yourself you won't get anything that ensures consistency of your field names. Just in your question you mention Scrapy, JSON, Django models, DRF serializers and Pandas. There's various other ways people could be modelling the same data, there probably isn't a one size fits all solution. Either you need to write some code that will generate the code / schema of these or you as the programmer just need to ensure that field names are correct as per the expectation.

I would use a StrEnum class to define field/attribute/column names in one place.
I just added a small classmethod to get the fields as a list.
from enum import StrEnum

class NoteSchema(StrEnum):

    TITLE = "title"
    CONTENT = "content"
    TAGS = "tags"

    @classmethod
    def list(cls):
        return list(map(lambda c: c.value, cls))

In places you need to use those fields for example with pandas you could then do this:
import pandas as pd
from dataschema import NoteSchema

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=NoteSchema.list())

df[NoteSchema.CONTENT] = [1, 2, 3]
df[NoteSchema.TITLE] = ["titleA", "titleB", "titleC"]

This would also give type hints and auto completion in most editors.

This won't work that easily with things like Django, etc. you'd need to create the model classes themselves dynamically if you want to follow an approach like this.

Yes, @AbdulAzizBarkat you are right. It won't work in scrapy or django. I try in Pandas and that is okay.

Another point, 'code'  from enum import StrEnum requires >= Python 3.11 and there is a module strenum that have similar features.
